# Selenium WebDriver + JUnit. Не видит элементы, которые обнаруживает Selenium IDE

Tags: java, webbrowser, selenium-webdriver, тестирование, junit

Всем доброго времени суток! Перешел с Selenium IDE на WebDriver + JUnit и имею следующую проблему: локаторы, которые раньше видел Selenium IDE в упор не видит WebDriver. 
Например:

**Команда из IDE**

```
waitForVisible -> xpath=.//*[@id='listContainer']
```

Элемент обнаруживается.

**Команда из JUnit:**

```
1.Assert.assertTrue("Element isn't exist", !driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='listContainer']")).isEmpty());
```

> Ошибка: Element isn't exist

**or**

Если попытаться найти по id

```
2.Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("listContainer")).isDisplayed());
```

> Ошибка: NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element...

Примечание:

Таймер стоит и элементы на странице прогружаются.

Полный код ниже:

```
public class Simpletest {
String baseUrl;
WebDriver driver;
    @Before
    public void testSetup() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
    }

    @After
    public void testShutDown() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldHaveTestAboutProfileSettings() {

        driver.get(baseUrl + "/SIMULATOR/index.html");
        wait(2);
    //   Assert.assertTrue("Element isn't exist", !driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='listContainer']")).isEmpty());
       Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("listContainer")).isDisplayed());

    }

  public void wait(int seconds) {
  try {
      Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

HTML:
[image: HTML]

В идеале, мне нужно проверить наличие clickItem с id=0

Comment: Ну селениум говорит, что не найдено такого элемента. Значит у вас его нет на страничке. Вы можете привести код тестируемой страницы?

Comment: еще уточню - у вас этот div находится непосредственно в html или же в каком-то frame?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov 1. К сожалению код полностью не могу выложить. 2. div непосредственно находится в другом css файле.

Comment: Эм, вы опечатались? Как может див находится в другом css файле?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov Да, я неправильно понял. Этот div находится непосредственно в html.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался в чем была проблема. Действительно, искомый элемент был связан с фреймом, а `webdriver` искал элементы в корне `html` страницы. Из этого получается, что `Selenium IDE` видит сразу всю структуру страницы и соответственно все элементы. Видимо поэтому проблемы раньше не возникало.
В итоге это решается путем переключения на нужный фрейм через команду:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("здесь id фрейма")));
```